# Configuring Delta build in Java Maven project

Tags: java, maven

My project is structured with a Parent POM and lots of modules each having child POMs themselves. Currently I'm doing a maven build with my Parent POM which is building the entire project. How can I convert this to a delta build i.e. I want to build only the module which has changed files?

I'm unable to find any plugins suiting this need. 
Another approach is writing a script to find the deltas and build individually.
Can someone please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified example? By default Maven >= 3.1 supports incremental builds. see option [useIncrementalCompilation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html), see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unrelated but if you know which module you are working on you can use Maven reactor to build this module with related dependencies by running:

```
mvn install -pl :my-module -am
```

> -pl, --projects
>
> Build specified reactor projects instead of all projects
>
> -am, --also-make
>
> If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list